# Section header visible when 'GONE'

Tags: android-listview, header, visibility

Simple custom adapter here, using one layout that includes a 'separator' textview that is shown when we get to the next 'letter' of our alphabetized list, or hidden if not.  Issue is the textview is showing for every item, and displaying numbers instead of letters.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

From the adapter:

```
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return myArr.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView separator;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView birdId;
    public TextView birdName;
    public TextView familyName;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    boolean needSeparator = false;
    String firstLetter;
    String firstLetterPrevious;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bird_entry, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.separator = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.separator);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        holder.birdId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.birdId);
        holder.birdName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.birdName);
        holder.familyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.familyName);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Determine points where a separator is needed: At the beginning and any
    // time the first letter of the bird name alphabetically increments
    firstLetter = myArr.get(position).get("fullName").substring(0,1);

    if (position == 0) {
        needSeparator = true;
    } else {
        firstLetterPrevious = myArr.get(position-1).get("fullName").substring(0,1);
        if (!firstLetter.equals(firstLetterPrevious)){
            needSeparator = true;
        }
    }

    if (needSeparator) {
        holder.separator.setText(firstLetter);
        holder.separator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.separator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    int ResID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(myArr.get(position).get("alphaCode"), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(ResID);
    holder.birdId.setText(myArr.get(position).get("birdId"));
    holder.birdName.setText(myArr.get(position).get("fullName"));
    holder.familyName.setText(myArr.get(position).get("family"));

    return convertView;
}
```

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/birdId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />


<!-- Left side Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_desc" />

</LinearLayout> 

<!-- Bird Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/birdName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<!-- Family Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/familyName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/birdName"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" />


</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that moving the separator TextView within the RelativeLayout solved the problem.  The new code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/birdId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff33b5e5" />

<!-- Left side Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/separator"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_desc" />

</LinearLayout> 

<!-- Bird Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/birdName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<!-- Family Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/familyName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/birdName"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Why?  No idea.